# Valid url and no urllib2.SocketError but got value error in python ('ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded')

Tags: python, json, urllib2, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a geographical converting API for some trajectory points, and the url was valid (using [JSOnLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to test), but got `ValueError`. Besides, I'm confused why it ran well a few weeks ago but raised an error today.

Below are the error messages and sample code

If I did not catch the `ValueError`

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-49502611c9d0> in <module>()
      5 ak = 'SWovHGOW7RV1kW4z1nbAsCAD'
      6 result_1 = geo_decoding(test_coord_array_1, 
----> 7                         test_coord_array_1.shape[0], ak)
      8 result_2 = geo_decoding(test_coord_array_2, 
      9                         test_coord_array_2.shape[0], ak)

<ipython-input-36-a93995bd86c7> in geo_decoding(coord_array, n_coord_array, ak)
     23             content = response.read()
     24             print content
---> 25             result = json.loads(content)
     26             response.close()
     27             return result

/home/*/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

/home/*/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    364 
    365         """
--> 366         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    367         end = _w(s, end).end()
    368         if end != len(s):

/home/*/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    382             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    383         except StopIteration:
--> 384             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    385         return obj, end

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import urllib, urllib2, json
from httplib import BadStatusLine

def geo_decoding(coord_array, n_coord_array, ak):
    trial = 0
    host = "http://api.map.baidu.com/geoconv/v1/?"
    if n_coord_array == 1:
        coord_string = coord_array[0]
        params = {'from': 1, 'to': 5, 'coords': coord_string, 'ak': ak}
    else:
        coord_string = ''
        for coord in coord_array:
            coord_string += coord + ';'
        params = {'from': 1, 'to': 5, 'coords': coord_string[0:-1], 'ak': ak}
    url = host + urllib.urlencode(params)
    print url
    while True:
        try:
            request = urllib2.Request(url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            content = response.read()
            print content
            result = json.loads(content)
            response.close()
            return result                  
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            trial += 1
            if trial <= 2:
                print 'e.reason.errno, try again...'
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                return None
        except urllib2.socket.error:
            trial += 1
            if trial <= 2:
                print 'SocketError, try again...'
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                return None
        except ValueError:
           trial += 1
            if trial <= 2:
                print 'ValueError, try again...'
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                return None
        except BadStatusLine:
            trial += 1
            if trial <= 2:
                print 'BadStatusLine, try again...'
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                return None

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        test_coord_array_1 = np.chararray((25,), itemsize = 256)
        test_coord_array_1[:] = '116.404,39.915;116.414,39.975'
        test_coord_array_2 = np.chararray((1,), itemsize = 256)
        test_coord_array_2[:] = '116.404,39.915;116.414,39.975'
        ak = 'SWovHGOW7RV1kW4z1nbAsCAD'
        result_1 = geo_decoding(test_coord_array_1, 
                                test_coord_array_1.shape[0], ak)
        result_2 = geo_decoding(test_coord_array_2, 
                                test_coord_array_2.shape[0], ak)
        print type(result_1), type(result_2)
```

---

Result:

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/geoconv/v1/?to=5&ak=SWovHGOW7RV1kW4z1nbAsCAD&coords=116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975%3B116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975&from=1
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


ValueError, try again...
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


ValueError, try again...
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


http://api.map.baidu.com/geoconv/v1/?to=5&ak=SWovHGOW7RV1kW4z1nbAsCAD&coords=116.404%2C39.915%3B116.414%2C39.975&from=1
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


ValueError, try again...
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


ValueError, try again...
<html><head><meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><script language=javascript>location='http://10.108.255.249/muxjp.php?url='+document.location;</script></head></html>


<type 'NoneType'> <type 'NoneType'>
```

But the output of `JsonLint` is valid:

for test_1:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "result": [
        {
            "x": 116.41662851562,
            "y": 39.922701508455
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670828652,
            "y": 39.982580969919
        },
        {
            "x": 116.4166274269,
            "y": 39.9227017898
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670474457,
            "y": 39.98258699539
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663150895,
            "y": 39.922701751779
        },
        {
            "x": 116.426710471,
            "y": 39.982584733879
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663504621,
            "y": 39.922702532438
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670610694,
            "y": 39.98258480313
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663259451,
            "y": 39.92270635216
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670801779,
            "y": 39.982587214783
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663368305,
            "y": 39.922706342017
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42671429148,
            "y": 39.982587657882
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663177739,
            "y": 39.922707444594
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670801551,
            "y": 39.982583687523
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663858522,
            "y": 39.922700601015
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670855839,
            "y": 39.982579608952
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663531729,
            "y": 39.922704157145
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670392386,
            "y": 39.982583209786
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662878582,
            "y": 39.922704489199
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670556213,
            "y": 39.982585897096
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662824225,
            "y": 39.92270340944
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670883412,
            "y": 39.982584217194
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662905796,
            "y": 39.922704486665
        },
        {
            "x": 116.4267031084,
            "y": 39.982587564011
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662932974,
            "y": 39.922705026544
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670883237,
            "y": 39.982581503918
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663341197,
            "y": 39.92270471731
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670747176,
            "y": 39.982586409456
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662878653,
            "y": 39.922703404371
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42671074165,
            "y": 39.982581473619
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663558713,
            "y": 39.922707680302
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42671128593,
            "y": 39.982579565669
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663205305,
            "y": 39.922702017916
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670719533,
            "y": 39.982580715903
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663341233,
            "y": 39.922704174896
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670746808,
            "y": 39.982580711575
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662769499,
            "y": 39.92270802503
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670610344,
            "y": 39.982579376577
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662851545,
            "y": 39.922701779662
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670392456,
            "y": 39.982584295097
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663695029,
            "y": 39.922703870721
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670801534,
            "y": 39.982583416196
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663259644,
            "y": 39.922703368881
        },
        {
            "x": 116.4267050175,
            "y": 39.98258726239
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663830851,
            "y": 39.922707654938
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670692345,
            "y": 39.98258207687
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41662823908,
            "y": 39.922708291169
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42671101633,
            "y": 39.982584453895
        },
        {
            "x": 116.41663477107,
            "y": 39.922707145496
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670392456,
            "y": 39.982584295097
        }
    ]
}
```

for test_2:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "result": [
        {
            "x": 116.41662769463,
            "y": 39.922708567445
        },
        {
            "x": 116.42670665244,
            "y": 39.982584794474
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope some one could point out the problem for me, thanks~

Comment: Well, as usual, extract a minimal example that shows the behaviour.

Comment: Where does your json samples come from ? Because there's no such json in your response's contents.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because this API has a limitation on the number of geographical coordinates, say no more than 100, so in first test I duplicated a pair of coordinates for 25 times.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the data was collected by GPS device equipped on taxis, but theoretically this API can accept any valid geographical coordinates of any country. I see the output of `response.read()` has a strange field `expires`, but I'm not quite sure about this because I have no knowledge about the `html` language and when I clicked the url directly it got normal returns, as the output of `JsonLint` showed. A few weeks ago   everything was ok but today...:(

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood me. I wanted to suggest that you create a minimal example containing both code and data. Your question as it stands is pretty vague. Also, if you did that, you would probably discover the error yourself.

Comment: @AnnabellChan: there's _no_ json at all in your responses, so your assertion that "the json is valid" is just plain wrong. If you read the response contents, you see HTML (which shouldn't be in a json response), and there's a javascript fragment redirecting to _another url_ - which I assume do serve the json. Looks pretty strange for what is supposed to be an API FWIW... Are you sure you're calling the right (documented) url ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's the network problem on my server. There is no error when I run it on my laptop. I use ipython notebook to work on the server, and I don't know what happened to the network of server, it can only ping campus network in a sudden...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the network problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've revised the problem

Comment: Ok, it definitely looks like something's wrong somewhere on your server / network / whatever, if it's your campus network then check this with the sysadmins. As far as I'm concerned I get valid json from your urls.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's **not** a coding problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks, I've flagged this problem